How to Preserve Session Data During POST Redirects from External Payment Gateways in Magento 2 with SameSite=Lax?
I’m working on a Magento 2 store that integrates with an external payment gateway, and I'm encountering issues with session persistence after a POST redirect back to my site. Specifically, the problem arises due to the SameSite=Lax cookie setting.
Context:

I’m attempting to replicate the session handling method used by PayPal in their Magento 2 integration.
My approach involves using an intermediate page that receives the POST request from the gateway and then internally redirects to the final page where the order is processed.
Despite following PayPal’s pattern, when the internal redirect occurs, the session data appears to be empty, causing issues with order processing.

Steps Taken:

Intermediate Page Setup: I’ve set up an intermediate page to handle the POST data and perform the redirect.
Session Handling: I’ve ensured that the session should be maintained across this process, similar to how PayPal does it.
Testing: During testing, I find that the session data is lost after the redirect, even though SameSite=Lax should theoretically allow the session to persist.

Questions:

Has anyone successfully implemented a similar solution? If so, how did you handle session persistence during the POST redirect?
Are there any Magento-specific configurations or best practices I might be missing that could ensure the session data is retained?
Is there a known workaround for this problem?

For reference, this issue has been discussed in detail on the Magento GitHub repository here, but I’m looking for further insights or solutions from the community.
